# Can the clearway be located on a lake?

Tags: faa-regulations, airport-design, declared-distances

From the [FAA AIM](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap4_section_3.html):

> All 14 CFR Part 139 airports report declared distances for each runway. Other airports may also report declared distances for a runway if necessary to meet runway design standards or to indicate the presence of a clearway or stopway. Where reported, declared distances for each runway end are published in the Chart Supplement U.S. For runways without published declared distances, the declared distances may be assumed to be equal to the physical length of the runway unless there is a displaced landing threshold, in which case the Landing Distance Available (LDA) is shortened by the amount of the threshold displacement.

Can the clearway be located on a lake?

Answer (score 6):

From [USA AIP](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aip_html/part1_gen_section_1.7.html) (emphasis added):

> The U.S. **does not require or provide criteria for clearways** in its design standards. It does encourage ownership and clearing of the land underlying the innermost portion of the approach out to where the approach surface is 10.5 meters above the level of the take-off surface.

You may also want to check [AC 150/5300-13A - Airport Design](https://www.faa.gov/airports/resources/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.current/documentnumber/150_5300-13) (no mention of water).

---

FWIW, ICAO includes water in the definition (Annex 14 to SARPs):

> ***Clearway.*** A defined rectangular area on the ground or water under the control of the appropriate authority, selected or prepared as a suitable area over which an aeroplane may make a portion of its initial climb to a specified height.

Comment: Provided the area is under control of the airport authority, that's an important point. You couldn't use a public lake unless the clearway area was somehow cordoned off.